# Is it possible to use a JSONDecoder() outside the init() to update an object's attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

I'm creating NSManagedObjects using Codable's `jsondecode.decode([User].self, from: jsonDataRaw)`
but my problem is that decode.decode() creates an new object every time , but instead I need a way to update exising objects with the jsonData rather than creating new ones.

Is there a way to do that using Codable?

```
class User : NSManagedObject, Codable {
   required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
            let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: MERUser.entityName, in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("Failed to decode")
        }
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
        try update(with: decoder)
    }

    func update(with decoder: Decoder) throws {

        // Decode
        guard let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) else {
                assertionFailure("no decoder")
                return
        }
        self.id = (try values.decode(Int64.self, forKey: .id))
        if let value = try? values.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .currentPoint),
            let unwrappedValue = value {
            self.currentPoint = unwrappedValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you already started working on the `update` function, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I believe the problem is how to call `update` from anywhere other than `init`. Like if you have new JSON from a server API and want to update an existing object in place instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, what Tom Harrington says is correct, I can't find a way to update an object with a decoder instead of creating a new object.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can but you'll need to roll up your sleeves a little. Stable Kernel has an article on how to approach this.

From the intro:

> As useful as these protocols are, they are missing one piece of functionality that I find is pretty common when working with remote services: the ability to update an existing model object from data. Building this functionality is a great exercise to get to explore the Codable protocols and related types.

https://stablekernel.com/understanding-extending-swift-4-codable/

Comment: Is there no simpler way to do this?